# Android: test from a service, if an Activity is running.

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have a service that runs in background. I I wish it could perform an action, only if a certain activity is running. How can I test, from a service, if the activity is running?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Package Manager and the Activity Manager:

[PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html): Class for retrieving various kinds of information related to the application packages that are currently installed on the device. You can find this class through `getPackageManager().`

[ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html): Interact with the overall activities running in the system.

But, a more simple approach would be: When starting your `Activity` (onCreate/onResume), send a message with service.send(..) or an Intent with service.onStartCommand(..) so the service knows that your particular Activity has been started.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it the other way around, sending intent from your activity to the service.

For example, you can send an intent on the activity `onResume`, telling your service the activity is live, and another on `onPause`, telling the service the activity has stopped

Answer (score 0):

Use the below method with your package name.It will return true if any of your activity is in foreground.

```
public boolean isForeground(String myPackage){
ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List< ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo > runningTaskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1); 

     ComponentName componentInfo = runningTaskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
   if(componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(myPackage)) return true;
return false;
}
```

Comment: But, I would know if a certain activity is running, not any activity. Can I test it?

Comment: Then you should check whether running activity is equal to the _certain activity_.